# Why iconv function return empty value if php variable contain quotes?

Tags: php, iconv

I try to change character encoding format tis-620 to unicode by using iconv function. `tis-t620` is Thai character encoding format. The reason for using iconv function is json_encode work only in unicode format.
Here is my code.

```
        $sql = "SELECT id,name FROM my_tbl WHERE id='$id'";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $name= $row['name'];
            $id = $row['id'];
        }
        $arr['name'] = iconv("tis-620","utf-8",$name);
        $arr['id'] = $id;
        echo json_encode($arr);
```

This code is work normally. But if the `name` contain double quote written by Thai language like this `“ทดสอบ”`, it return empty value. I don't know why. I very appriciate any suggestion.

Comment: If you need to get data in UTF-8 from your database, it usually makes more sense to set the database connection to `utf8` so the database will do the conversion for you. – Unless you're somehow mishandling the encoding to begin with and it's stored in some weird form in the database already...

Answer (score -1):

Try http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

```
$sql = "SELECT id,name FROM my_tbl WHERE id='$id'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  $name= $row['name'];
  $id = $row['id'];
}
$arr['name'] = mb_convert_encoding($name, "tis-620","utf-8");
$arr['id'] = $id;
echo json_encode($arr);
```